# Cocoapods - 'pod --version' gives me 0.31.1 after updating to 0.32.1

Tags: xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I have basically the same question as this post: [when running pod install I get The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1, try updating but still in 0.31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165446/when-running-pod-install-i-get-the-master-repo-requires-cocoapods-0-32-1-try) but the answer doesn't help me (I'm not allowed to comment on things yet haha!)

I try to run 'pod install' or 'pod setup' and I get an error saying:

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1 - 
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.5.0/lib/claide/command.rb:281:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.5.0/lib/claide/command.rb:274:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.31.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.31.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Then I run 'sudo gem install cocoapods' and I get:

```
CHANGELOG:

## 0.32.1

##### Bug Fixes

* Fixed the Podfile `default_subspec` attribute in nested subspecs.  
  [Fabio Pelosin][irrationalfab]
  [#2050](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2050)


Successfully installed cocoapods-0.32.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.32.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Even after this, I run 'pod --version' and I still get 0.31.1. Is there another step I need to take to successfully update to 0.32.1?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Update: HAD TO RESTART TERMINAL after `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

Then `sudo gem install cocoapods` updates to the latest version successfully.

Comment: It's showing me an error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj`   - What's solution of this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Run `pod --version` and `sudo pod --version` - I imagine multiple versions have been installed with and without sudo.  Either update both, or remove the undesired second one with `[sudo] gem uninstall cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks, I had to run both "gem uninstall cocoapods" and "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods" in order to get this to work

Answer (score 4):

Try uninstalling the gem first:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then install it again:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then `pod --version` should show the newest.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have tried that several times as well. Do I need to install or uninstall while in a certain directory? I'm performing these commands while in my xcode project directory, but I doubt that matters.

Comment: Yea that shouldn't matter. If you still can't get this to work correctly I'd try setting up ruby through something like RVM or rbenv.

Comment: yea I'm using rbenv.. Restarting Terminal fixed the issue after uninstalling.

Comment: Oh with rbenv you shouldn't have to use `sudo`. Also make sure to run `rbenv rehash` after each of these.

Answer (score 3):

What finally worked for me was...

```
- sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
- Restart the Terminal ( on your Mac)
- sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

also , better copy paste, easy to do a typo with Cocoapods :-)

Comment: "NOT Restarting the Terminal" was my issue. Thanks Naishta!

Answer (score 2):

I am using bundle, so `bundle update cocoapods` works for me.

Comment: this helped me! I was stuck on cocoapods 1.10.0 but when updating it keep saying already in 1.10.1. anyways that command saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem is caused by two versions of cocoapods have been installed.

I uninstalled cocoapods first by running `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`.

And then run  `pod --version` command to check the existence of cocoapods again.

Wierd thing happened! The gem is there.
So I uninstalled cocoapods for the second time.

My conclusion is to make sure you delete all cocoapods completely, and reinstall it. It works for me.