# 'gem uninstall cocoapods' not uninstalling

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

After failing to manage installing properly the Jekyll gem (website dev), the problem started out with `pod install` returning the infamous message described also in other questions on this site ([when running pod install I get The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1, try updating but still in 0.31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165446/when-running-pod-install-i-get-the-master-repo-requires-cocoapods-0-32-1-try) and others)

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1 - 
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:217:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Running `pod ver` returns 0.29.0 even though I successfully installed 0.32.1.
I noticed that the above message points to the 0.29.0 install directory, which does not match the current installation directory (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems)

I've run through all possible gem commands iterations but still can't come out on top of it (cleanup, uninstall, install, etc).
gem check returns the following:

```
xcodeproj-0.16.1.gem has 5 problems
  ext/xcodeproj/Makefile:
  Extra file
ext/xcodeproj/extconf.h:
  Extra file
ext/xcodeproj/mkmf.log:
  Extra file
ext/xcodeproj/xcodeproj_ext.bundle:
  Extra file
ext/xcodeproj/xcodeproj_ext.o:
  Extra file
```

Don't know if it relates.

Removing the `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/` directory returns errors on any pod command.

Short of reinstalling the whole operating system(!)--which, tested on a fresh volume, proved solving the issue--can't figure this one out.
Any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be using RVM and installing gems into a gemset. If that is the case, then it is possible for you to have multiple versions of the same gem installed on your system simultaneously.

If you want to update the system-wide gem, use `sudo`, e.g. `sudo gem install cocoapods`. If you want to update the RVM, exclude `sudo`, e.g. `gem install cocoapods`.

Also be sure that if you are using an RVM, you are not running `pod install` as root, either.

Comment: You are right, it looks like something like that. RVM is not in use though, I did tried anyway to probe this route but nothing worked.