# Cocoapods installing old version of Stripe library by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, stripe-payments

Currently attempting to set up Stripe in a fresh iOS app in Swift using the following guide: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios. Immediately ran into trouble with Cocoapods. The repo can be found here: https://github.com/ktransier/stripeTest/blob/master/Podfile

First attempted using the line:

```
pod 'Stripe'
```

This resulted in:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing PaymentKit (1.0.2)
Installing Stripe (1.0.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

I need version 2.2.1 (the latest version), but it is installing 1.0.2.

Next I attempted to use the explicit version number, as copied off the Cocoapods site:

```
pod 'Stripe', '~> 2.2'
```

Terminal output:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `Stripe (~> 2.2)` required by `Podfile`
```

Here's my stack:

```
CocoaPods : 0.34.4
Ruby : ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.1]
RubyGems : 2.4.1
Host : Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Xcode : 6.1 (6A1052d)
Git : git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

How can I install the latest Stripe library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your local copy of the specs repo hasn't been updated in a while. Try running

```
pod repo update
```

Comment: Thanks! Right on the money, needed to remove the repo and reinstall the gem, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23342957/4233556