# No such Module IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Tags: ios, swift, module, keyboard, identifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dFDm.png)I am new to `iOS` `Swift` and trying to install this framework.

I have installed this framework by `cocoa pods` and add this line in app delegate

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift & IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

I am now getting this error (

> No such Module IQKeyboardManagerSwift)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the swift and Xcode version that you are using and if that version support the pod file you are using

`Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3)` Use:-

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

Or

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.3'
```

For `Swift 2.1.1 (Xcode 7.2)` Use :-

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.0'
```

For `Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.0)` Use :-

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '3.3.3.1'
```

I had similar problem , turns out i had two Cocoapods instances installed, This is a Cocoapods issue not an Xcode one (in my case it was').

All i needed to do was uninstall my cocoapod and reinstall it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940867/6297658......
This worked for me...

Once you are done reinstalling go to your pod file add pods according to the version of swift and Xcode you are using and then run `pod install`

PS: Cocoapods REPO is nearly 350MB, so if your download is stuck don't just quit `Terminal` and start reinstalling again first uninstall `Cocoapods` and `old master repo` both completely, then start installing again ... this is probably what caused two instances of it in my case

Comment: thanks it really work , feeling like i complete 1 milestone

Comment: So what was it multiple instances or pod version?

Comment: yeah i think so because after that it works perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, when I install a new Pod, I need to clean & build the project.

```
Clean build folder: Alt+Shift+Cmd+K
Build: Cmd+B
Run: Cmd+R
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

***First of you should replace***

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

***By***

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

**Then use *"Command+Shift+K"* then *"Command+b"*  then *"Command+r"***

**Also If the issue is resolved then it's Good to go else you can use these terminal commands to update project pod repo:-**

*Go to the project directory in terminal then run following commands*

```
pod init
pod deintegrate
pod repo update
pod install --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

It is issue when intsall through pods so drag and drop its file then wrtie this line in appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

Answer (score 0):

In may case the following solution worked:

Replaced 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' with 'IQKeyboardManager'